# What is the SQL to delete a SQL User from a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the SQL to delete a SQL User from a database?

Comment: Which database? SQL Server? Oracle? The answer will vary by RDBMS vendor.

Comment: It's a MS SQL Server database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DROP USER [UserName]
```

You can prefix this with an existence check if required.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'UserName')
```

There are some requirements to be met before dropping Users (e.g. they can't own any objects). [Full Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx).